# Cross join end up giving "No space left on device"

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to cross join two data frames and apply few transformations and finally trying to write the result into temp S3 location. But I am always ending up with below `No space left on device` error. Looks like it is due to calling `spill()`. Could you please help me how to overcome this error with the correct configurations?

Configuration details:

- Cluster: AWS EMR cluster
- CORE nodes: 2 initially and it scaling up to 15 nodes.
- TASK nodes: 0 initially and it scaling up to 15 ON-DEMAND basis.
- instance type: r4.2xlarge (8 core, 61GB RAM, 128 EBS)
- Dataframe1 & Dataframes2 partitions size: 26 partitions.
- Dataframe1 record count = 115580
- Dataframe2 record count = 94191
- Dataframe1 columns count: 53 ( 1 column holding JSON data)
- Dataframe2 columns count: 36
- spark.sql.shuffle.partitions: 500
- "spark.executor.memoryOverhead": "4852"
- "spark.driver.memoryOverhead": "4852"

Error:

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 63 in stage 68.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 63.3 in stage 68.0 (TID 1640) (ip-10-66-199-71.ec2.internal executor 44):
> org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: error while calling spill() on org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter@7ea8a25 : No space left on device
>
> org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: error while calling spill() on org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter@7ea8a25 : No space left on device

Thanks in Advance..!!
Sekhar

Comment: A cross join? You want to select ten billion rows? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Its a common issue, and AWS provides official documentation on how to solve it:

- [How do I resolve "no space left on device" stage failures in Spark on Amazon EMR?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-space-left-on-device-emr-spark/)

Comment: Thank you Marcin for your suggestions. Even though I have increased EBS volume by allocating 15 more nodes, still I am getting same error.

Comment: So I have decided to use r4.4x large instances which will give 256GB EBS volume per node and ran the same, still got the same error. I am totally frustrated with this. 

Is there any other way to achieve this??

Comment: Below are the configuration details: 
-----------------------------------
instance type: r4.4xlarge (16 core, 122GB RAM, 256 EBS)

Dataframe1 & Dataframes2 partitions size: 26 partitions.

spark.sql.shuffle.partitions: 900

"spark.executor.memoryOverhead": "4G"

"spark.driver.memoryOverhead": "10G"

--deploy-mode client 
--num-executors 88 
--executor-cores 5 
--executor-memory 37GB 
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4G 
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=10G 
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=900